# Reading a string from a file with C. Fopen with w+ mode is not working

Tags: c, file, fopen

I made a C program that reads a string from a `.txt` file, then it encrypts the string, and finally it writes the string in the same file.

The thing is that if I use `fopen("D:\\Prueba.txt","w+")`, the program doesn't work, it prints garbage like this `)PHI N`.

I've debugged and I know the error is there in that line, because if I use `fopen("D:\\Prueba.txt","r+")`, the program works, and it writes what it should.

But I want to use `w+` because it will rewrite what the `.txt` file had. Why is `w+` not working?

Answer (score 5):

If you're opening with `w+` to first read the content, that's not going to work. From `C11`:

> `w+`: ***truncate to zero length*** or create text file for update.

What's probably happening is that you read data from the now empty file but don't correctly check that it worked. That would explain the weird "content" you see of `)PHI  N`.

One solution is to open the file as with `r`, open another file with `w`, and transfer the contents, encrypting them as part of that process. Then close both, delete the original, and rename the new one to the original name. This will allow you to process arbitrarily-sized files since you process them a bit at a time.

If you don't want to use a temporary file, and you're sure you can store the entire content in memory, you could open it `r+`, get the content, the reopen it with a new mode, such as with:

```
FILE *readFh = fopen( "myfile.txt", "r+");
// Read in content, massage as needed.

FILE *writeFh = frepoen( NULL, "w+", readFh);
// Provided that worked, you should now have an empty file to write to.
// Write back your massaged data.
```